# Inserir arquivo JSON no JSFiddle

Tags: json, jsfiddle

Estou tentando resolver uma dúvida com um plugin que usa jQuery mas não sei como inserir um arquivo JSON no JSFiddle.

Esse JSON é uma *string* e vem de um arquivo `.json`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depende um pouco de onde vais buscar o JSON.

Se fôr uma string podes colar diretamente no espaço de JavaScript:

```
var str = '{"objeto": {"foo":"bar"}}';
var json = JSON.parse(str);
```

se fôr um ficheiro maior eu costumo colocar num script ajax:

```
function buscaJSON(url, cb) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      cb(null, data);
    } else {
      cb('Error: ' + request.responseText);
    }
  };
  request.onerror = function() {
    cb('Unknown error');
  };

  request.send();
}

buscaJSON('https://rawgit.com/SergioCrisostomo/version-files/master/json_example.json', function(err, json) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(json, null, 4));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/35hg40bz/

Comment: Consegui! Eu criei no Github e depois gerei um Raw, assim como no seu exemplo.

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida boa! é mto util, fiquei contente quando descobri essa possibilidade também.

Comment: Bem, agora eu posso preparar meu problema real! Parece que os moderadores não gostam quando a gente diz "obrigado", então, *Danke Schön*